# Mysql statement insert, if inserted, insert another

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the following statement:

```
INSERT INTO `Properties`(`Id`, `Url`, `BrokerId`, `LastFound`) VALUES
(@Id,@Url,@BrokerId,@LastFound)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE LastFoundOn = @LastFoundOn;

INSERT INTO `Events`(`Id`, `Type`, `DateTime`, `PropertyId`) VALUES
(@EventId,@EventType,@Now,@Id);
```

There is a foreign key constraint between Properties.Id and Events.PropertyId. And the Url is unique.

This works - almost. When a recod is not inserted, but updated because of duplicate key (Url), then the insert into event will fail, because the foreign key simply doesn't exist. Like this:

Eg:

```
exists:    1  |  http://test1.com  |  2  |  2013-03-13
to insert: 2  |  http://test2.com  |  2  |  2013-03-14
```

When trying to insert, it updates instead, because of the unique url. When afterwards trying to insert the event, a foreign key (2) doesn't exist in the Properties table. How can I make an if then statement to handle this scenario?

Something like (?):

```
INSERT INTO `Properties`(`Id`, `Url`, `BrokerId`, `LastFound`) VALUES
(@Id,@Url,@BrokerId,@LastFound)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE LastFoundOn = @LastFoundOn;
IF LastInserted = @Id THEN
INSERT INTO `Events`(`Id`, `Type`, `DateTime`, `PropertyId`) VALUES
(@EventId,@EventType,@Now,@Id);
END IF;
```

UPDATE:

A trigger might be the solution, but I'm struggeling making it work. What's wrong here?

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER Event_Submitted_Trigger AFTER INSERT ON Properties 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Events VALUES(SELECT(UUID()), 'PropertySubmitted', SELECT(NOW()), new.Id);
END$$
```

I get the following error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT(NOW()), new.Id); END$$' at line 4

Best regards,

Søren

UPDATE:

Here is my schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Events` (
  `Id` char(36) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `Type` enum('PropertySubmitted','PropertyChanged','PropertyRemoved') NOT NULL,
  `DateTime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `Attribute` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `From` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
  `To` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
  `PropertyId` char(36) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  KEY `IX_FK_PropertyEvent` (`PropertyId`),
  KEY `DateTimeIndex` (`DateTime`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `Properties`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Properties` (
  `Id` char(36) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `Url` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `Type` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `ExtractedAddress` varchar(192) NOT NULL,
  `ExtractedPostcode` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `ExtractedCity` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `StreetName` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `StreetNumber` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Floor` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Side` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DoorNo` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Postcode` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `City` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Latitude` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `Longitude` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `ImageUrl` varchar(512) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `Price` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `Payout` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `GrossPrice` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `NetPrice` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `Area` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `GroundArea` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `Rooms` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `Year` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `PriceChange` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `FirstFoundOn` datetime NOT NULL,
  `SubmittedOn` datetime NOT NULL,
  `LastFoundOn` datetime NOT NULL,
  `FoundAt` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Validated` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `BrokerId` char(36) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `Archived` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Url` (`Url`),
  KEY `IX_FK_PropertyBroker` (`BrokerId`),
  KEY `UrlIndex` (`Url`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Triggers `Properties`
--
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `Event_Submitted_Trigger`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `Event_Submitted_Trigger` AFTER INSERT ON `Properties`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
 INSERT INTO `Events` VALUES(UUID(), 'PropertySubmitted', NOW(), NEW.Id);
END
//
DELIMITER ;

--
-- Constraints for dumped tables
--

--
-- Constraints for table `Events`
--
ALTER TABLE `Events`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `Events_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`PropertyId`) REFERENCES `Properties` (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

--
-- Constraints for table `Properties`
--
ALTER TABLE `Properties`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `Properties_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`BrokerId`) REFERENCES `Brokers` (`Id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

Comment: @Soren....are you trying to accomplish this with one SQL Statement?

Comment: Not sure that I understand; you're saying that in the event of a key collision during the first insertion, the `Properties` table is updated (as desired), but that the insertion into the `Events` table fails?  Why does that insertion fail?  Another key collision perhaps?  Do you simply want to use the `IGNORE` keyword?

Comment: This is done in one statement. Ok, to clarify. The Id of the property trying to insert is different from the existing one, but Url is also unique and that's what makes it a duplicate. Thus the property should be inserted correct, but because the PropertyId used to insert the event now doesn't exist, the complete statement fails.

Comment: I'm still struggling to understand.  Perhaps some example data would help?

Comment: So I would need somehting like (pseudo): insert into properties on duplicate update; if inserted insert into events;

Comment: Did you mean: "When a record is not inserted, but updated because of the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` clause, then the subsequent `INSERT` *must* fail."

Comment: No it will fail, because of a foreign key contraint. But I want it to only execute if the first statement actually inserted.

Comment: Would this simple be easier to do by making a trigger?

Comment: Actually I believe a trigger is the only way to achieve this in pure (My)SQL.

Comment: Ok. Edited with a not working trigger. How should it be modified?

Comment: Use `NOW()` instead of `SELECT(NOW())`.

Comment: That gives me: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5

Comment: Also use `UUID()` instead of `SELECT UUID()`.

Comment: That changes nothing.

Comment: Hold on I will come back with a full solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE Properties (
    id         INT,
    url        VARCHAR(100),
    lastFound  DATETIME,
    UNIQUE (url)
) ;

CREATE TABLE Events (
    id         VARCHAR(36),
    type       VARCHAR(20),
    t          DATETIME,
    propertyId INT
) ;
```

Here is a working trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER Event_Submitted_Trigger AFTER INSERT ON Properties 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Events VALUES( UUID(), 'PropertySubmitted', NOW(), new.Id);
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

See it in action [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7321d/1). Notice the `NOW()+SLEEP(1)` hack, only meant to delay execution in order to get a significant result (`SLEEP()` returns 0 if not interrupted).

Comment: The trigger is now accepted, but I get a "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1" when trying to insert. I guess that has something to do with the trigger? I've added my schema to the initial question.